# Error al consumir api rest de Laravel desde Ionic

Tags: php, laravel, ionic, api, ionic-framework

Tengo un API rest creado en laravel y cuando trato de consumirlo desde ionic me genera un error que no lo he podido solucionar. He pensado de colocar una condicion que cuando la ruta es api me arroje los datos en json de lo contrario me envie a la vista a laravel. pero no he podido de definir y colocarla como parametro. Alguna sugerencia?

**Codigo de api rest en laravel**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

  //ruta api que muestra los clientes  
  Route::resource('clientes','ClienteController@index');
```

**aqui estan las rutas que me muestra laravel**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**archivo ClienteControlador**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Persona;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests\PersonaFormRequest;
use DB;

class ClienteController extends Controller
{
    public function __contruct()
    {

    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request) {
            /*obtener todos los registro de la base de datos de una determinada categoria
            trim:quita espacios*/
            $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

            /*se almacena en la variable categoria la consulta de buscar por nombre la categoria y donde la condicion de la categoria este activo*/
           $personas = DB::table('persona')
                ->where('nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->where('tipo_persona', '=', 'Cliente')
                ->orwhere('num_documento', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->where('tipo_persona', '=', 'Cliente')
                ->orderBy('idpersona', 'desc')
                ->paginate(5);

                  json_decode($personas);

            //devuleve una vista donde lleva dos parametros
            return view('ventas.cliente.index', ["personas" => $personas, "searchText" => $query]);
        }

    }
```

**archivo modelo persona**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{
    protected $table='persona';
    protected $primaryKey='idpersona';
    public $timestamps=false;

protected $fillable=[
    'tipo_persona',
    'nombre',
    'tipo_documento',
    'num_documento',
    'direccion',
    'telefono',
    'celular',
    'email'
];

protected $guarded=[

];
```

}

**archivo index donde muestra los clientes en laravel**

```
@extends('layoust.admin')
@section ('contenido')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>       
 Listado de Clientes
        <a href="cliente/create">
            <button class="btn btn-success">
                Nuevo
            </button>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <!--se incluye la vista search, que es una barra de busqueda-->
    @include('ventas.cliente.search')
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Nombre
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Tipo Doc
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Numero Doc
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Telefono
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Celular
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Opciones
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <!--Bucle que recorre todas las personas-->


                @foreach ($personas as $per)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ $per->idpersona}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $per->nombre}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $per->tipo_documento}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $per->num_documento}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $per->telefono}}
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        {{ $per->celular}}
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        {{ $per->email}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <!--link q llama el controlador editar y pasa como parametro el idpericulo-->
                        <a href="{{URL::action('ClienteController@edit',$per->idpersona)}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-info">
                                Editar
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        <a data-target="#modal-delete-{{$per->idpersona}}" data-toggle="modal" href="">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                Eliminar
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @include('ventas.cliente.eliminar')
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--mostrar paginacion con el metodo render-->
        {{$personas->render()}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

***a continuacion los archivos de ionic framework***

**proveedor1.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//se importa el httcliente
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Proveedor1Provider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello Proveedor1Provider Provider');
  }

  obtenerClientes(){
        return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ventas/cliente');
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

//se incorporan las paginas con clase y ruta

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { YoutubePage } from '../pages/youtube/youtube';
import { MasinfoPage } from '../pages/masinfo/masinfo';
import { RejillaPage } from '../pages/rejilla/rejilla';


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Proveedor1Provider } from '../providers/proveedor1/proveedor1';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    YoutubePage,
    MasinfoPage,
    RejillaPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    YoutubePage,
    MasinfoPage,
    RejillaPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Proveedor1Provider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
//se importa el providers para poder utilizar la conexion
import { Proveedor1Provider } from '../../providers/proveedor1/proveedor1';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

//variable clientes
    clientes 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public proveedor:Proveedor1Provider) {

  }

//funcion que obntiene los clientes que los trae tipo json
ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.proveedor.obtenerClientes()
    .subscribe(
        (data)=>{this.clientes=data;},
        (error)=>{console.log(error);}
    )

}

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Inicio</ion-title>
     <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<h2>Datos servidor externo</h2>
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let cliente of clientes">
    {{cliente.nombre}}
  </button>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**estos son los errores que me muestra la consola**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya probaste que la API funcione correctamente antes de consumirla con IONIC ?

Comment: En laravel estas declarando las rutas mal, revisa la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @crrlos Si me funciona

Comment: @Xerif Disculpa no veo que las estoy declarando mal, me funciona normal cuando corro en laravel.

Comment: @Juanzu Haz un `php artisan route:list` y revisa el action, esas rutas estan mal declaradas. Aparte de que en Ionic llamas a otra ruta diferente `/ventas/cliente`

Comment: @Xerif Si tienes razon, ya lo modifique y mi pregunta tambien, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando consumes una API vía get, el sistema debe evaluar los headers y verificar que todo se encuentre en orden, ver que es permitido consumir la información desde donde la petición se realiza. El error es que el control de acceso de HTTP, llamado CORS, debe ser configurado para ser consumido. No es un error de rutas, sólo necesitas un plugin que pueda configurar eso por ti, por mientras puedes hacer que tu API sea consumida por cualquier persona, pero no es una buena práctica cuando lo saques a producción.

Checa este plugin: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Gracias, ya aregle esa parte. No me da ningún error pero tampoco me lista la información